# Is there a `map()` like operation in git, to create a modified copy of each revision as another branch?

Tags: git, git-history-rewrite

I would like to create a copy of a branch history (all the way from the initial commit to the current state, with all the merges, etc), but I need to apply a custom logic at each revision - something like running a `get_all_revisions_in_order().map(my_custom_logic)`.

So if a git repo has just one file in format A, and each revision modifies that one file, I would like to produce another branch that has exactly the same history (i.e. log messages and branching/merging structure), also with just one file, but that file will be in format B.  My script would look at each diff in the original file's revisions, and apply the same changes to the file in the new format.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase , https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch , https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Comment: Thx @phd, I think the filter-repo is the most promising one (rebase seems not relevant, and filter branch is not recommended for use?).  I am still trying to understand how to make the filter-repo do what i need...

Comment: `rebase` is perfectly relevant, why do you think otherwise? Interactive rebase, I mean — it runs through all commits you want; you can make it automatic using `--exec`

Comment: There is nothing built in for doing exactly that, but Git contains all the tools you need to write your own. The most basic part of the tool is `git rev-list` (all the other tools that @phd noted are built on `git rev-list` here). Use rev-list to generate the hash IDs of the commits you want, then do your operation on those commits.